# Load more option in list view did not show previous list in android

Tags: android, json, listview, baseadapter

i have parsed Json data from the server. On which im showing all the data in listview and i have Load more option below the `ListView`. Now when i click **load more** option, this application reload whole list and did not show previous list data. Please help me find out the solution. Here is **footer view click listener :**

```
lFooter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        page += 1;
        new ParseIssues().execute();
        listView.removeFooterView(v);
    }
});
```

in **above** code `ParseIssues` class parse `json` values and displays all the data in `ListView` Here is code for `onPostExecute` of `AsynkTask` class :

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if(page < totalPage){
        listView.addFooterView(v);
    }

    listAdapter = new ListAdapterForSearch(activity, mainList);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    // get listview current position - used to maintain scroll position
    int currentPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    listView.setSelection(currentPosition);
}
```

Here is **BaseAdapter** class:

```
public class ListAdapterForSearch extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public ListAdapterForSearch(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_item, null);
        }

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title);

        HashMap<String, String> hash = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hash = data.get(position);

        title.setText(hash.get("title"));

        return vi;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add the new data that you get in `mainList`

Comment: Do you add the newly fetched data to `mainList`or create a new list with the new data ?

Comment: Creating every time a new adapter is kinda bad practice. Where the "mainList" is coming from ? How you populate that list ?

Comment: I think lFooter.setOnClickListener add next data on mainList is it true or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in your code you may have clear your `mainList`.

Comment: Oh sorry, its funny. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Welcome. If my ans helps you then please accept the answer.

Comment: Answers like this should be put in comments. Guessing is not the best way to go about on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question lies with the variable "mainList", which the adapter uses. You need to add the new data to it, basically this list needs to contain all the data you want to show in your ListView.

Answer (score 0):

You should set adapter on create, after that first add loaded data to mainlist(add new loaded data) & then after loading notify adapter like listadapter.notifydatachange()

Edit: Because every time you are creating adapter that's why you are facing this problem, instead after loading just notify your adapter..